# Writing Python toolbox that gives two options for one parameter?

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox

I'm working on a Python toolbox that buffers features using slope distance based on an input DEM rather than horizontal distance. The tool works great with buffer widths derived from a field in the input feature.

I'd like to add the option to buffer by one given width like the ArcGIS proximity tool, Buffer, resulting in a radio button choice:

[image]

Comment: You will need to try and use checkboxes to achieve an analogous effect. Doing precisely what you want is not possible without dropping ArcPy and using ArcObjects instead.

Comment: I had this open when I saw @PolyGeo 's comment:

   `param2 = arcpy.Parameter(`
     `name = "moveTapToBP",`
     `datatype = "GPBoolean",`
     `parameterType = "Required",`
     `direction = "Input")`
    `param2.value = False`

I use this checkbox and then a conditional statement on the existence of the moveTapToBP variable to achieve a similar logic split... I can't figure out how to format to get code on correct lines in the comment, help appreciated

Comment: @maverickGIS please ask questions as a new question, not as a comment on someone else's question.  See [ask].

Comment: @midavalo Sorry, I wasn't asking a question, I was providing poorly formatted example, the help request was only to clarify my code for that purpose

Comment: @maverickGIS Answers should be given as answers - you can format your code in the answer.

Comment: @Midavalo would this be considered an answer since it isn't what the original question asked for? I have been told not to do such things, but would be happy to

Comment: @Ian Yau, I have the same question. Do you manage to do it?

Comment: @MikV89, please see my solution post below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got to where I wanted to go using the updateParameters and updateMessages functions:

```
def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    if parameters[0].altered:
        if parameters[0].value:
            parameters[1].enabled = False
        else:
            parameters[1].enabled = True
    if parameters[1].altered:                
        if parameters[1].value:
            parameters[0].enabled = False
        else:
            parameters[0].enabled = True
return

def updateMessages(self, parameters):
    if not parameters[1].value and not parameters[2].value:
        parameters[1].setErrorMessage(
            '''Either parameter 1 OR parameter 2 must be supplied, but not both.''')
        parameters[2].setErrorMessage(
            '''Either parameter 1 OR parameter 2 must be supplied, but not both.''')
    elif parameters[1].value and parameters[2].value:
        parameters[1].setErrorMessage(
            '''Either parameter 1 OR parameter 2 must be supplied, but not both.''')
        parameters[2].setErrorMessage(
            '''Either parameter 1 OR parameter 2 must be supplied, but not both.''')

return
```

When the tool loads, the parameters appear as though required, with the green dot:

[image]

If both parameters are populated, then it becomes a red error X with the error message:

[image]

The updateParameters function disables the other parameter once one parameter is populated.

Answer (score 2):

I use a checkbox and then a conditional statement on the existence of the moveTapToBP variable to achieve a similar logic split.

```
param2 = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName = "Move un-snapped taps to their building points",
    name = "moveTapToBP",
    datatype = "GPBoolean",
    parameterType = "Required",
    direction = "Input")
param2.value = False
```